# how to use android process button lib

Tags: android, eclipse

I've download [android process button lib](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button) and import it into my eclipse.  :

android process button lib :

[image]

I created an android project then I added this lib into my project :

[image]

now, I want to use this library but I get this error :

> ProgressGenerator cannot be resolved to a type

[image]

I am using eclipse.

Comment: try a clean & build of your project

Comment: I tested earlier. did not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@NIPHIN answer is correct. As you can notice library is using gradle folder structure.

Here are 2 options:

1. Move `com.dd...` folders to src folder.
2. Create new project library, and simply copy all `res` and classes to your new created folder.

Answer (score 1):

CHeck the project structure, reorganize the folder "java" to reflect folder structure as same folder "src" in eclipse. Eclipse and Studio IDE have different folder structures.

Comment: reorganize the folder structure as told by Dmytro Danylyk.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure of how you integrated it, but the example clearly state to import

```
import com.dd.processbutton.iml.ActionProcessButton;
import com.dd.processbutton.iml.GenerateProcessButton;
import com.dd.processbutton.iml.SubmitProcessButton;
```

Even though the project has been added as a dependency library, you would still need to have these import statements. May be eclipse is having trouble automatically adding these imports? Jut add them i manually. If your folder structure and import are correct, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thread is a bit old, but perhaps I can help you out.

I´ll show you an Example with the ActionProcessButton

first of all in your layout, u need the specific Button. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.dd.processbutton.iml.ActionProcessButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            custom:pb_colorComplete="@color/green_complete"
            custom:pb_colorNormal="@color/blue_normal"
            custom:pb_colorPressed="@color/blue_pressed"
            custom:pb_colorProgress="@color/purple_progress"
            custom:pb_textComplete="@string/login_successfull"
            custom:pb_textProgress="@string/login_auth" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

inside your activiy / Fragment / whatever:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

                private ActionProcessButton loginButton;

                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
            loginButton = (ActionProcessButton) view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

     loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            loginButton.setProgress(50); // starts the Animation and sets the text defined in your .xml file for Progress
                         loginDone();
                        }
                    });

            }
            private void loginDone(){
             //...
             // do something time-consuming
            loginButton.setProgress(100); // tolds the button, that your operation is done.

            }
// ...
}
```

Of course, you can update the Progress state dynamically, but as I know, the critical values for setProgress are -1(for login failed), 0, 50 and 100.